# Identification of a mysterious lifeform, what is this?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

For the third time in a row, I found a mysterious life-form inside my house. I live in the Netherlands in the Eindhoven region, in a city called [Oss near a forest area](https://maps.google.nl/maps?q=maps+oss&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x47c6fc89edf0a983:0xd870787dc357c409,Oss&gl=nl&ei=TH3zUqWkGsO8ygPV-ILoCA&ved=0CDEQ8gEwAA). Before I set it free outside, I put it in a jar to make a few pictures for identification purposes. What is this creature?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How big is this bug? Do you have a photo where the markings on the back can be seen better?

Comment: Wow, the site is getting bigger, we actually already have a question about this insect (or a very close cousin), voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Chris The creature is about 3~4 centimeters long, including the legs. If I'd have to estimate the body, I'd say roughly ~2 centimeters. terdon; It does not seem to be the same one?

Comment: @terdon I think so, too. Its hard to say which one exactly from the images since the back is not clearly visible.